# This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or does not support them

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ibm-mobilefirst

I have installed Visual Studio 2012, and I have developed a WindowsPhone8 Application in Worklight 6.1.

Now I am trying to open that .csproj into studio 2012 will prompt me an error
"This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or does not support them"".

Can any one help me ? How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you installed Windows Phone SDK 8 ?

Comment: Are you on Windows 8 ?

Comment: Yes I am working on windows 8 and installed Windows Phone SDK as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to open a project WP8 on Visual Studio, you must have :

- Windows 8 or Windows 8 Pro
- VS2012 or 2013
- WP SDK 8

source : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=265773